# Reset QMenu to accept new set of QActions

Tags: c++, qt, qmenu

I wish to reset/recreate a custom context menu. I am using QMenu and QAction(member variables) to achieve this.

```
 QMenu* m_menu;
 QAction* m_actionTitle;
```

I have the slot connected like this:

```
connect(m_ui->actionLoad_Definition_File, &QAction::triggered, m_Item.get(),
        &Item::loadDefinitionFilesFromMenu);
```

**Working part:**

In my constructor i have setup something like this:

```
 Item::Item(QWidget* parent)
 {
     // Connect context menu
     this->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
     connect(this, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)),
        this,   SLOT(showContextMenu(const QPoint&)));  
 }


/* virtual */ void Item::showContextMenu(const QPoint& pos)
{
    // Obtain global position
    QPoint globalPos = mapToGlobal(pos);

   // Change the first menu entry to show the range
   m_actionTitle->setText(QString::number(m_from) + " - " +
                       QString::number(m_to));  //Access Violation error

   QAction* action = m_menu->exec(globalPos); 
   if (action != NULL)
   {
      if (action->text() == "something")
   {
        // Remove the item
        m_view->removeItem(this);
   }
   else
   {
        // Display the text
        setText(action->text());
        setColor(action->text());
        setToolTip(action->text());
        m_edit.setText(action->text());
        m_view->arrange();
   }
 }
}
```

**What I want:**

I want to reset `m_menu` of all its actions and push new actions into it. So, whenever i right click, the new context menu should show up.

**The Problem:**

After creating the QToolButton if i right click on it i get "Access Violation Error". Debugging it, both m_menu and m_actionTitle are going out of scope or simply destroyed. Not sure why is this happening.

**What i did so far:**

```
void Item::loadDefinitionFilesFromMenu()
{
    //Clear the vector of existing values
    m_defaults.clear();
    //Clear the menu of actions
    m_menu->clear();

    QString file = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(nullptr, "Choose a definition file", QString(),
                                            QString("(*.ad)"));

    if (!file.isNull())
    {
        MLParser ml;

        std::map<std::string, std::string> base = ml.readDefinitions(file.toStdString());

        for (auto const& gestureValues : base)
        {
            m_defaults.push_back(gestureValues.first);  // string (key)
        }

        m_menu = new QMenu(this);
        m_actionTitle = new QAction("Note", m_menu);
        m_actionTitle->setEnabled(false);
        m_menu->addAction(m_actionTitle);
        m_menu->addSeparator();

        for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = m_defaults.begin();
         it != m_defaults.end();
         ++it)
        {
            m_menu->addAction(QString::fromStdString(*it)); //works ok
        }

        m_menu->addSeparator();
    }
}
```

I would like to reuse `m_menu` throughout my program but i am not able to get it to reset and accept new set of actions. Am i missing anything here?

**EDIT 1:**

Removed `QMenu` and `QAction` in the constructor. Only inside the `loadDefinitionFilesFromMenu`.

Comment: I'm simply creating a new menu and actions every time the context menu is opened.

Comment: What's this Item class? Are there many instances of it? Why each one has its own menu?

Comment: You create your menu actions from `m_defaults` and read defaults from a definition file. Probably you load the same `file.ad` each time?

Comment: @vahancho no as you can see i am using a file dialog to select a different file and i am pretty sure it is a different file.

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o Item class inherits QToolButton. Yes i am using multiple instances of it throughout the project.

Comment: @MarKS do you realize that when you *load* a menu from file you're only changing **that** menu, which belongs to just one tool button? Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o infact, you are right! creating a new item would call the constructor and it would show up the old menu again. But now i have edited the question to only initialize QMenu and QAction inside the function. But when i right click it m_actionTitle inside the showContextMenu gives "access violation error". Most probably it is destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the menu shared among all `Item` instances.

In Item class header:

```
private:
    static QMenu* m_menu;
    static QAction * m_actionTitle;
    static std::vector<std::string> m_defaults;
```

In Item class cpp, after defines and before method definitions:

```
QMenu* Item::m_menu = 0;
QAction * Item::m_actionTitle = 0;
std::vector<std::string> Item::m_defaults;
```

The menu is instantiated only once, in `Item` constructor:

```
if(m_menu == 0)
{
    m_menu = new QMenu();
    // load defaults here
}
```

No need to instantiate the menu again: remove this line from `loadDefinitionFilesFromMenu`:

```
m_menu = new QMenu(this);
```

About your `m_actionTitle` pointer: don't assign a new `QAction` to it, let it hold the return value of `addAction` method:

```
    m_actionTitle = m_menu->addAction("Note");
    m_actionTitle->setEnabled(false);
    m_menu->addSeparator();
```

Finally, have a static method to delete the (one and only) menu instance. In header file:

```
static void dismissMenu();
```

In cpp:

```
void Item::dismissMenu()
{
  delete m_menu;
}
```

You can call this method before exiting, after `QApplication::exec` returns:

```
Item::dismissMenu();
```

Comment: I edited the answer, hope it's ok now. Not sure if `m_defaults` needs to be static, though.

Comment: I came up with something similar with static. While trying your code i get error at `m_actionTitle = m_menu->addAction("Note", m_menu)`. Going through addActions overload i see that it is expecting some sort of slot or pointer to an object. Hence the signal slot error i suppose. Not sure is it because it is static.
`error C2338: Signal and slot arguments are not compatible`
`error C2228: left of '.()' must have class/struct/union`

Comment: I have edited a part of your code to make it right. This combination actually worked for me. The credit still goes to you for pointing out static stuff so i will mark your comment as an answer.

Comment: why do i need to delete `m_menu` explicitly even though it has a parent?

Comment: Ok @MarKS, I rolled back to my initial answer: don't parent the menu! It's static, so it's shared. What if a parent goes out of scope? The shared menu will be deleted ... I corrected a mistake also, it's the line `m_menu->addAction("Note");` which should compile now.